# How do I make a bar plot with different color bars?

Tags: matlab, histogram

I have an array data such as: `A = [5 7 8 9 10 ... 98]`

I want to plot a bar graph using this data with different color bars. I couldn't figure out how to separately color individual bars or groups of bars. I can only plot them all with the same color.

For example, I want to plot this type of data like this: green bar for `5`, red bars for `7` to `10`, etc..

Comment: I there some rule for grouping the elements in `A` together?

Answer (score 1):

The function `bar` called on a vector creates a single graphics object that can only have one color.  To get a bar chart with bars of different colors at arbitrary locations you can call `bar` multiple times with different x coordinates:

```
A = [1,2,3,4,5,6,2,3,4,6,1];

figure
hold on

bar([1], A(1),'FaceColor','r');
bar([2:3], A(2:3),'FaceColor','b');
bar([4:7], A(4:7), 'FaceColor','g');
bar([8:11], A(8:11), 'FaceColor','m');
```